# Dynamic Tab Pages cannot be found within Tab Control

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs

Good afternoon my fellow propeller heads; I come to you with a very strange issue today.

In my C# Winforms application, I have a form with a Tab Control. The Tab Control has 4 Tab Pages which I added during design. When my application runs, I am adding x amount of Tab Pages dynamically.

My issue lies not with any of the Tab Pages I added at design time, but only with the dynamic Tab Pages. The dynamic Tab Pages have buttons, which fire fine when clicked. However, when I iterate through the Tab Control’s Tab Pages, only the static Tab Pages are present, none of the dynamic pages are in the control.

I have a class that creates my Tab Pages and it all works fine and adds the Tab Pages as it should. The class name is TabTree and the method name is Add_Tree_View_Tab. "test tab" is the text being displayed on the tab. The null parameter is irrelevant at this time as it is input to another control docked on the Tab Page.

```
tabRecords.TabPages.Add(TabTree.Add_Tree_View_Tab("test tab", null));
```

I have also added just a Tab Page to see if I could find it within the Tab Control, but still no luck.

```
tabRecords.TabPages.Add("this page", "this page");
```

Trying to find either of my dynamic Tab Pages yield no result?

```
internal void Expand_Treeview(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Button button = (Button)sender;

        foreach (TabPage tab_page in tabRecords.TabPages)
        {
            if (tab_page.Name == "tab_" + button.Tag.ToString())
            {
                foreach (Control control in tab_page.Controls)
                {
                    if (control is TreeView && control.Name == "treeview_" + button.Tag.ToString())
                    {
                        TreeView Tree_view = (TreeView)control;


                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    { }
}
```

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing? I have spent a good couple of ours trying to figure this out with no solution as yet…

Comment: Post just relevant code. The code which you shared contains some irrelevant parts, for example if/foreach. Also it lacks required part of code, for example `TabTree.Add_Tree_View_Tab`. Also it's not clear what the problem you are facing with and what exception or error you receive. Please read about [MCVE] and [ASK].

Comment: Add a breakpoint at the line
`tabRecords.TabPages.Add`, after a page is added, check whether the number of pages in TabPages collection is increased or not?

Comment: Hi @RezaAghaei; appologies if you didn't understand my question but I thought I made it quite clear. Simply, I cannot seem to find any of the Tab Pages I add dynamically to a Tab Control. No exceptions are thrown.

Comment: @kennyzx I add the dynamic pages on Form Load. When I set the breakpoint as you suggest, the pages are indeed there. When I iterate through the Tab Control after the application has loaded, they are "missing"?

Comment: Hi @Bazïnga You can simply add a tab page this way `tabControl1.TabPages.Add("tabname", "tab text");` and you can simply find it by name this way: `tabControl1.TabPages["tabname"]`. That's easy. So you need to debug your application to see where the problem is.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I have tried what you suggested. The Tab Page returns null. I am absolutely 100% sure that the tab name is correct , and I just double checked it. I appreciate your input! That is why I find this issue so strange I have added controls dynamically plenty of times but have never experienced this issue. When I do a tab page count on the tab control, on form load it is 7 which indicates my tabs were created, but on the button click event it count only 4, which are the design time tabs.

Comment: Anyway, the code which you shared with us is not enough to help you. It doesn't help us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: So it is not WYSIWYG? You are seeing 7 pages while the program tells you 4? Try to rebuild you project. I think something wired happens, I cannot repro this from a newly created project.

Comment: I also suspect you are looking into two different instances. Any way, I'll vote to close the question *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [MVCE].*

Comment: @kennyzx exactly that. When the form loads and I query the count, it shows 7. On the form itself it shows all the tabs. But as soon as I fire the click event there is only a count of 4, the original 4 which was added in design time. I have rebuilt my project, no luck

Comment: @RezaAghaei I am suspecting you are spot on. There are a lot of classes inheriting from each other in order to build the complete tab dynamically. I will investigate this and provide feedback once I have an established the cause.

Comment: Maybe the key can not contain spaces..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help from everyone, you definitely put me on the right track. It was a case of different instances and destroyed objects.

There are two classes that create the dynamic tabs. The first class is instantiated, but also inherits from the second class. Also, the second class inherits from the actual form, in order to be able to add the dynamic buttons event handler that exist on the tab page. The tabs are created but as soon as the first instantiated class is destroyed, all reference to the dynamic tabs are lost. Which makes perfect sense. I didn't pick up on it as it is code I inherited.

Once again thanks for everyone's input to get me sorted.